# Angular Select NgOptions double selecting when directive compiles

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I am working on a dynamic form that populates a dropdown conditionally based on another input. I have written a directive because the data that comes back will also carry validation rules that need to be applied. However when i apply the validation rules to the dropdown and recompile the select options are borked. The final HTML looks like this:
[image: Double Selected Options]

The questions on the form can depend on another to be answered in a very specific way before they appear. This dropdown for example depends on the country selected but can be required or optional depending on what country is selected. The data coming back from my server gives me a validation object that contains validation information for the input field such as:

```
  var question = scope.question;
        var input = element.find('select');
        if (question.validation.required) {
            if (!input.attr('required')) {
                input.attr('required', question.validation.required);

            }
        }
        $compile(input)(scope);
```

The standard `<option value="?" selected="selected"></option>` is put in but when the question the dropdown depends on triggers the watch and a request happens for the dropdown the server returns and the backing select values are changed but the HTML output results as seen above all the items that are set to selected are unselectable and the form validation fails.

```
  function answerMatch(countryCode) {
            sectionService.getDivisionsByCountryCode(countryCode).then(function (response) {
                scope.question.selectValues = response.data;
                element.show();

            });
        }
```

and an HTML snippet for good measure

```
 <select id="question{{question.questionId}}" name="answer" ng-model="question.value" ng-options="value.text for value in question.selectValues" class="form-control">
</select>
```

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: Let me try the application is pretty complex I will see if I can distill out the things that would work.